# Windows 10 PC Freezes Every Few Minutes then Resumes. Hard Restart NOT Required.

Tags: windows-10

For the past few months my PC has been freezing every half-hour or so. The task does not seem to matter, it's happened when gaming, or just using a web browser. The mouse and keyboard will completely stop responding for 1 to 2 minutes, after which it resumes as if there were no issue. I've closed all possible applications save the ones I'm running, I've gone to make sure no extensive background processes are running, and my PC is currently up to date.

Things I've noticed:

- It does not freeze when videos are playing, even longer movies. Seems to be tied to increasing input frequency. i.e. Opening a few new tabs, typing and switching between input fields quickly, switching between programs like evernote and chrome.
- If I
  press Ctrl+alt+delete while it is frozen, it will bring up the task
  manager page once it resumes (this is what i've been doing to avoid
  frantically moving my mouse around to figure out when it's running
  again). So the computer is taking commands while frozen, but not able to execute until it resumes.

System Details

- Edition: Windows 10 Home
- Processor: Intel i5
- RAM: 12 GB
- System Type: 64-bit

Apologies if this has been asked. I've not seen a problem like this that does not require a hard reset of the computer.

Comment: Sounds like an I/O issue

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on this or point me to a relevant reference? There's a good deal on this when I do a quick google, would help to narrow down what I'm looking for.

Comment: How can I reference my nearly 2 decades of experience?  By I/O issue I mean your HDD obviously

Comment: @Ramhound FYI... despite my own two decades of experience I/O does not instantly mean HDD to me. There are many different kinds of I/O. That said, I do agree, this sounds like a classic HDD failure-in-progress issue. Likely bad sectors or possibly a failing read-write head. But that only makes sense if using an HDD and not an SSD. Regardless, I suggest backing up critical data before doing any diagnostics... diagnostics may push a failing drive over the edge and kill it completely.